# Why before_create callback overrides create! params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

This code drives me crazy. Should not passed params inside `create!` method override `padding` value set by `set_padding` method?

```
Banner.create!(padding: {left:100, right: 200, top:300, bottom: 400})
```

> INSERT INTO "banners" ("padding", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES
>   ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["padding",
>   "**{\"top\":20,\"bottom\":25,\"left\":60,\"right\":60}**"], ["created_at",
>   "2017-03-10 08:37:00.183376"], ["updated_at", "2017-03-10
>   08:37:00.183376"]]

As you can see thanks to `before_create` callback a record with another `padding` value is created. Why did `before_create` override my passed params? I thought that first a `before_create` callback is called and then `create!` is executed, therefore - overwriting model attributes, previously modified by `before_create`...

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: banners
#
#  id                  :integer          not null, primary key
#  padding             :text

class Banner < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :padding, JSON
  before_create :set_padding

  def set_padding
        self.padding = { top: 20, bottom: 25, left: 60, right: 60 }
    end
end
```

Comment: Not sure but I guess that it works like "First build the object with supplied attribute and then run the before_create callbacks and finally save" so the second step of running callbacks, overrides the attributes of object.

Comment: It would make sense for me if `after_create` callback would override `padding` attribute, but not `before_create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that first a `before_create` callback is called and then `create!` is executed, therefore - overwriting model attributes, previously modified by `before_create`.

Nope, your understanding is wrong. `before_create` callback has actually *nothing to do* with `create!` method. For example, it will be invoked here as well:

```
banner = Banner.new(...)
banner.save
```

`before_save` / `before_create` are called right before object is about to be saved to the database. This is a last chance to modify/massage data or abort the operation.

Comment: >`before_create` callback has actually nothing to do with `create!` method It's like saying 'delete_object' has nothing to do with deleting an object :)

Comment: @yaru: but it's true, there's no direct link. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I debugged a Rails behavior.

```
def set_padding
  byebug # <----
  self.padding = { top: 20, bottom: 25, left: 60, right: 60 }
end
```

On this `byebug` line `self.padding` is set to `{left:100, right: 200, top:300, bottom: 400}` but as you guessed - a line below it will override it to another value...

So the solution for me was simple - do not allow this method to execute if `self.padding` is set to something.

More specifically I changed this line:

```
before_create :set_padding
```

to this:

```
before_create :set_padding, :if => lambda { |banner| banner.padding.nil? }
```

Answer (score 0):

**before_create:**

will be called before saving new object in db. When this method will return false it will prevent the creation by rolling back.

So when you need to do something like check something before saving which is not appropriate in validations you can use them in before_create.

For example: before creation of new Worker ask Master for permission.

```
before_create :notify_master
def notify_master
  # notify_master via ipc and 
  # if response is true then return true and create this successfully
  # else return false and rollback
end
```

Another use is that you want to format some attribute before saving like capitalizing name etc.

**after_create:**

Called after saving object in database for first time. Just when you don't want to interrupt creation and just take a note of creation or trigger something after creation this is useful.

for example: After creating new user with role mod we want to notify other mods

```
after_create :notify_mod, :is_mod?

def notify_mod
  # send notification to all other mods
end
```